# Learning Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Am newbie in Laravel (am using the latest version) and have the following in my "routes.php" file:

```
 Route::get('/books', function(){
        return 'Books Index';
    });

 Rout::get('/books/{genre}', function($genre){
         return "Books in the {$genre} category";
    });
```

If i  enter these in my browser ::

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/books             // first address
http://localhost/laravel/public/books/movies     // second address
```

to test both addresses, i get the error page(s) that says something went wrong. If i comment the second route and try the first address then it works. The second address never works even if i comment the first route. Thus as long as both routes are present, none of the addresses work.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the closing brackets and parenthesis on the second route, was this just a typo?

Comment: @user3158900 it was a typo otherwise the IDE wouldn't have allowed me to run the code. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your second route, you are missing an *e* (Rout != Route). With a syntax error like that your routes file will not execute correctly.

I would have just added a comment, but my reputation is not good enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in the future, your laravel project should be writing errors like this to a log file somewhere. This should be defined in the file app/start/global.php in a block like the following:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Error Logger
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will configure the error logger setup for the application which
| is built on top of the wonderful Monolog library. By default we will
| build a basic log file setup which creates a single file for logs.
|
*/

Log::useFiles('/var/log/laravel/laravel.log');
```

Tailing this log file should give you some insight when you run into issues working on your project.

Comment: I believe is better to use a relative path: `Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have slash at beginning of route, use only:

```
Route::get('books', function(){ ...
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "Rout" -> "Route"

```
Route::get('/books/{genre}', function($genre){
     return "Books in the {$genre} category";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have syntax error, Please on the debugging mode in app/config/app.php file. Laravel provides a well formatted error messages else default it will shows the 'something went wrong'

Following the syntax

Old code

```
'debug' => false
```

New code

```
'debug' => true
```